# Can I avoid permission_required decorator on Django testing?

Tags: python, django, testing

I am testing a set of Django applications which make extensive use of the 'permission_required' decorator. This derives in a 302 HTTP response in most of the views that I have.

My question is: there is any way to avoid or deactivate the 'permission_required' in testing, so I can get a 200 response when I call my views, instead of the 302?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just log in with a superuser in your test case setUp method

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class TestThatNeedsLogin(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        User.objects.create_superuser(
            'user1',
            'user1@example.com',
            'pswd',
        )
        self.client.login(username="user1", password="pswd")

    def tearDown(self):
        self.client.logout()

    def test_something(self):
        response = self.client.get("/")
        self.assertEqual(200, response.status_code)
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I have created a testing user exactly in the way you say, but it seems that the 'is_superuser' param is not working for me. I can't access to the views, since them are returning me a redirection to 'unauthorized' page. Of course, this does not happens in the normal behavior of the app when I try to access to views with a superuser.

Comment: Okay, the way is not to assign a 'is_superuser=True' to the user when you create the new object, but to use the more specific 'create_superuser' method. I will write this as the effective solution for my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could monkey patch it:

```
import django.contrib.auth.decorators

real_permission_required = decorators.permission_required
# return a function that returns the exact function that was decorated, ignoring arguments
decorators.permission_required = lambda *args, **kwargs: lambda func: func
```

You need to make sure this happens before it's used, which is at the **definition time** of the object it's decorating. (For example, when that module is included.)

It also has to happen before it's rebound to another scope. After `import django.contrib.auth.decorators` is fine, but before `from django.contrib.auth.decorators import permission_required`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but seems a little bit tricky and I usually prefer to don't override the framework native methods. Anyway, it would be interesting to do what you propose.

Finally, I have solved it logging a user with the Client.login() method and accessing the views with this. That is the best way to test all, because you test both the views and the 'login_required' or 'permission_required' decorators.

Again, thank you!

Cheers,
Jose

Comment: Yep, that sounds like the best way. Why not edit your question to add the solution?

Comment: I am not sure now, because this does not allow my user to access to the views, despite it have been created with is_superuser = True.

Answer (score 0):

Well. The solution I have found is to create a superuser in the setUp method from the TestCase class. I did it in that way:

```
def setUp(self):
    self.client = Client()
    self.user = User.objects.create_superuser(
        'testuser',
        'test@example.com',
        'easy_password',
    )
```

Then, when I want to test a URL, I do this:

```
def test_search_customers(self):
    url = reverse('customer_search')
    response = self.client.get(url)
    # Not logged user. Must return a 302 HTTP code.
    self.assertEquals(response.status_code, 302)
    self.assertEquals(response['Location'], 'http://testserver/unauthorized/?next=/search/customers/')
    # HERE I LOG IN MY SUPERUSER
    self.client.login(username='testuser', password='easy_password')
    response = self.client.get(url, follow=True)
    # Same URL requested with a logged user with permissions. Must return 200 HTTP code.
    self.assertEquals(response.status_code, 200)
```

This is what it worked for me :)

Thank you all. Cheers,

Jose

Comment: If you're gonna do it like that, I'd break it into two tests. One to make sure they are redirected without permission:  self.assertRedirects(response, 'http://testserver/unauthorized/?next=/search/customers/'   and the next to log in with your super user and make sure it does the right thing.